# Color emoji problem in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10, emoji

I read Gnome 3.26 introduced support for coloured emoji, but I can't understand how to install or make them work and where to find them. I only see them in monochrome. I'm searching but I don't find nothing useful. Can you help me?

Comment: "*The Color Emoji feature of GNOME 3.26 is not available in Ubuntu 17.10.*": from the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes) for Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color emoji fonts won't be available in Ubuntu 17.10. Missing requirements are:

- cairo 1.15.8
- fontconfig 2.12.5
- a color emoji font

The top two requirements are low-level libraries and therefore are not good candidates even for a PPA for 17.10, but they will likely be available in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Source: [Ubuntu Desktop Trello Card](https://trello.com/c/FVcXa6l7/21-color-emoji-support)

Comment: Oh, well, thank you! I'll wait for the LTS for that :)